# Is there a synonym suggestion keyboard out there for iPhone

Tags: iphone, keyboard, messages

I just want to know if there is a more comprehensive dictionary and ideally synonym suggesting keyboard for an iPhone.

Comment: Let me know if my answer helps you by commenting or pressing the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

I found two apps that might fit this bill:

The first: a keyboard with synonym suggestions. ($4), [Hemingboard Rhymes, Puns, and Synonyms keyboard.](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hemingboard-rhymes-puns-synonyms/id1019312381?mt=8)

The second: a word processor with advanced features including synonyms/antonyms. ($4), [WriteRight.](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/writeright-enjoy-writing/id671844532?mt=8)